# How can I stop explode rounding a value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

$user->height = 5.10

`print_r(explode('.',$user->height))`

Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 1 )

How to do I get the second value to display as 10?

FYI 
 `print_r(explode('.',5.10))`

outputs the same.

Comment: Explode works on strings....

Comment: @m1kfb That's probably because your `$user->height` is not a string, and it is already lost at that point. You need to convert it to a string before the height is set.

Comment: Assuming this is a value representing feet and inches, you should not store it as a float. Even converting it to a string will be problematic. What if your user has a height of five feet, one inch? Do you store 5.1? As a float, 5.1 and 5.10 are the same number.

Comment: @Don'tPanic it's not my logic unfortunately I have to live with it but values under 10 get stored with sprintf('%02d', $value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to explode a number.

The number is dropping the 0 as a number because it's irrelevant as a number. You'll have to convert your number to a string and then pad it if necessary.

```
$number = 5.10;
$string_version = number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
print_r(explode('.', $string_version));
```

Comment: Thanks, this was at the end of a long day :/

Comment: You're welcome, but assuming it's a fraction of a height as @Don'tPanic suggested, you will have some serious problems here. As there will be no different between 5.1 and 5.10 even though you are candy-coating it. Are we to assume 5' 1" is 5.01? and 5' 10" is 5.1? Just food for thought. Have a good night.

Answer (score 0):

> print_r(explode('.',5.10))

The trailing zero is dropped before the value gets into explode. As long as you don't use a String, trailing zeroes will be omitted.

```
<?php

    $height = 5.10;

    header( "Content-Type: text/plain" );

    // Outputs: height = 5.1
    echo( "height = " . $height . "\r\n" );
    print_r( explode( ".", $height ) );

?>
```

Comment: I know. My answer refers to the simplified case given by the questioner (the part after "FYI".) My "before" means: It's not due to explode as the questioner thinks (see the title of the question: "How can I stop explode rounding a value?"). I already happens *before* explode even sees the value. whereever `$user->height` is assigned.